# Conversion of one or more characters from XML to target collation impossible

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

When i am transferring a varchar field which is casted from xml. transfer from one server to another it shows a error 
error msg shown

> Msg 6355, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion of one or more characters from XML to target collation impossible

Comment: Everybody posting questions here wants answers as quickly as possible. Your question is no more (nor less) urgent than anyone else's questions.

Comment: Also, the error message is reasonably straightforward - you have some characters in your XML document that *cannot* be stored in that `varchar` column. Either the collation for that column is incorrect, or you need more flexibility in the value that you can store and it should be an `nvarchar` column instead.

Comment: thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 50, accepted):

At last got it 
This is due to 'र' in the xml column.
It does not support to cast to varchar so i cast the xml field to nvarchar.

Comment: How to convert to nvarchar and then to use LIKE ? Do you have any example?

Comment: where cast(Property as nvarchar(max)) like '%whatever%'